# Retweet specific user. Tweepy & python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have this code that retweets a tweet if that said tweet includes the mention of @oogabooga.
How would I change it so that it would retweet every tweet tweeted by @oogabooga without the need of a mention in those said tweets?
So basically I want to retweet everything that @oogabooga tweets, regardless of content. I tried modifying it myself and went through tweepy docs, API, and looked up some similar problems trying to build from there, but with no luck. Help a noob out!

```
import logging
import time
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('hiddenkey1','hiddenkey2')
auth.set_access_token('hiddenkey3','hiddenkey4')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

user = api.me()

def fav_retweet_user(api, user_handle):
    search_query = f"{user_handle} -filter:retweets"
    logger.info(f'Retrieving tweets mentioning {user_handle}...')
    tweets = api.search(q=search_query, lang ="en")
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None or \
            tweet.user.id == api.me().id:
            return
        if not tweet.favorited:
            try:
                tweet.favorite()
                logger.info(f"Liked a tweet mentioning {user_handle}")
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on fav", exc_info=True)
        if not tweet.retweeted:
            try:
                tweet.retweet()
                logger.info(f"Retweeted a tweet mentioning {user_handle}")
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on fav and retweet", exc_info=True)

while True:
    fav_retweet_user(api, "@oogabooga")
    logger.info("Waiting...")
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: If you changed your search query to `from:{user_handle}` it would find Tweets they posted; but, you should read the Twitter Automation Rules to avoid having your app suspended for spammy behaviour https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation

Comment: @AndyPiper when I change my `search_query = f"{user_handle} -filter:retweets"` to `search_query = from:{user_handle}`, it says _SyntaxError: invalid syntax_ and points to it. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your search query to the following will work:

```
search_query = f"-filter:from:{user_handle}"
```